# I have a python program, but how can I display the data onto a NodeJS based web application?

Tags: python, node.js

Currently built a python program that gathers data.

I have a set of data, but my web application will run NodeJS for the backend.

How do I display the data collected into my NodeJS application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on how large the data is and on how your nodejs backend is constructed. You can always send post-requests to your webserver with your data.

`r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})`

For more information see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Another way would be saveing your data into a database and read it from your webapp.

Comment: Okay cool. I understand that part. And you're right having the program take the data and saving it into my database would be THE way. But one question that keeps bothering me is how would I run this program in the cloud alongside my web application? I'm not always going to run the program on my computer when the data needs to be updated. How would I do this automatically (in the cloud) when the need arises?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean with „cloud“? If you have an amazon-aws instance, you can run all, the webserver, database and python script in it. How does the script generate the data?

Comment: That's what I meant. Would I be able to have the python script and my web application in Amazon AWS and have them talk to each other?

Comment: yeah sure! You can have as many scrips running in parallel as the vcpu can handle.

Comment: The post request would go to your localhost, though.

Comment: So a hypothetical situation: If there was an apartment listing site, and 
if their primary source of data was scraping apartment listing sites, they would be using the python script for scraping the data from the websites and then display the data on the frontend. Would this be possible or is this how they're accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes, probably they would use the APIs of these sites to scrape the data via the python script, then save the data into a database and use a nodejs server to display the data into the frontend and filter it.